# Applying ng-class conditionally by model method

Tags: angularjs, model

I have a list of DIVs that are generated by ng-repeat.
I need to apply an ng-class to those that're selected. To find out if the div is selected, I call to a model function ( not ng-model, just standard conceptual model ).

```
<div class="default" ng-class="{selected : myModel.isSelected({{item.id}})}" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <!--Div content-->
</div>
```

This doesn't work, and none of the divs get the selected class.
However, when I call the model function from the inspector (myModel.isSelected(id)) for a specific id constant, I get "true".

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: `myModel` is sitting in `scope` ?

Comment: Try to remove the `{{}}` in the method call and check.

Comment: myModel is a global variable. Removing the {{}} changes nothing.

Comment: Seems like you need to create some "proxy" method in a scope

Comment: I've created an isSelected function in the respective controller that calls the model, still not working. Any ideas how I can debug the ng-repeat?

Comment: when it fails? does a `model`'s `isSelected` fires?

Comment: Without any other part of code, the problem could come from many things, I tried to implement myself something similar, and it works well : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/yuQ5x/1/ , but I just removed the {{}} from your code

Comment: ASFAIK the expression used in ng-class needs to resolve within the scope context, so angular is looking for `myModel` on the current scope. The way you have defined your model as global in not the angular way. You need to provide more context.